# No detecta la carpeta donde viene la imagen Android Studio

Tags: android, imagen, android-layout, enlace

Hola a todos ando realizando una app de bitacora de frutas.

Creo que es algo muy comun el problema soy nuevo en esto que eh andado buscando en tutoriales y blogers pero sin resultado no me lo detecta en el layout la carpeta "frutas" las demas carpetas si lo que me hace pensar que tengo que autorizar la carpeta "frutas" para que lo lea la app que ando realizando pero no se como espero que me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Los archivos de recursos como imagenes deben agregarse ùnicamente dentro de los directorios `/drawable` o los directorios `/mipmap` de sus distintas densidades, estos directorios se encuentran dentro de `/src/main/res/`.

No es posible registrarlos en otro directorio dentro de tu proyecto. Incluso si configuras ["Flavors" en tu proyecto](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?hl=es), tambièn debes usar los directorios   `/drawable` o los directorios `/mipmap` de sus distintas densidades.

Revisa :

[Cómo configurar variantes de compilación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?hl=es)

Comment: Entendido a la perfeccion, saludos y gracias @Jorgesys!